# How would an English speaker pronounce "valid" with a circumflex over the A?

Tags: pronunciation, foreign-phrases, international

My branding department (read my friend from work) has suggested the word "vâlid" with a circumflex over the A as a way to brand my product.  He just likes the way a lowercase a looks in typography.

Can anyone tell me how that would be pronounced, or what it would sound like in different languages?

I read [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex), and think it's the same "a" sound, but with a stronger first syllable?

[image]

Comment: Most people would be confused, and some would be put off by it being "too cute".  I'd pronounce it either as normal or as "va-LID".  (Just winging it, mind you.)  (I'd also, knowing it was an advertisingism, work on finding other ways to mispronounce it, and likely use a different pronunciation every time.)

Comment: A circumflex has no meaning in English orthography. It'll mostly just confuse people.

Comment: I would probably think it was meant to look pseudo-French and therefore apply (pseudo-)French rules, pronouncing the _â_ as [ɑ:] (like the _a_ in _father_).

Comment: It just looks weird. Like this: vͮ̃ͬͩ̈̐â̧̏̒̈͌ͪlǐ̆ͥd́͆̉̒

Comment: I'm not sure what his affection for the lowercase *a* has to do with his decision to suggest a circumflex.

Comment: It is not a standard symbol in phonetics,  nor in English phonology, nor in English spelling. There is no single way that English readers would pronounce it, since they would figure that it must not be the real word _valid_ because that isn't spelled that way, so it must be a foreign word that's pronounced differently (and who knows what it means, anyway -- if it was really _valid_, they'd just say so, right?). So readers would hafta figure it out, and they'd each come to their own pronunciation. If they bothered to. Which most wouldn't; after all, it's just an ad.

Comment: @IanMacDonald This person likes the shape of the lowercase a in the font, and likes it for flare

Comment: @makerofthings7: which explains why the person may choose to use a lowercase *a*, but doesn't explain the choice to add a circumflex.

Comment: @IanMacDonald There are many choices designers make that I can't explain.

Comment: To Everyman, this looks like the word *valid* with an arrow pointing up. Many people couldn't identify a circumflex accent in a lineup of diuretic medicines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most English speakers wouldn't know what to do with an â inside an otherwise English word and no context regarding source language. Some people will simply ignore the circumflex and pronounce the English word; we've seen companies do this enough times that it's lost part of its charm. Some people will go out of their way to pronounce it differently, but they will not be consistent about it.

Eventually, people will find a source of record. When we have the opportunity and the curiosity, we will ask a person how they pronounce their unusual name. Similarly, those who have the opportunity and interest will ask someone affiliated with the name (an owner, manager, or other employee) how it is pronounced.

Comment: See also Häagen-Dazs, Spın̈al Tap,TETЯIS, Plymouth Volaré, Mötley Crüe, Queensrÿche, Blue Öyster Cult, Deathtöngue, Fahrvergnügen, Micro$oft, Orac£e, Womyn, &c ad furōrem.

Comment: Fahrvergnügen is unlike the others (it's a regularly spelled German word)

Comment: @tchrist Has Accenture applied for a Unicode codepoint for their *greater than t*? I always found that one unusually irksome— there are countless existing characters to misuse, from Наӥв to Hλlf-Life; why suggest a new one?

Answer (score 3):

I went to a French Wikipedia page on [circumflex](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe). It has the advantage over the English page in that it shows how different languages treat vowels with a circumflex.

Under the French section, it says:

> Dans d'autres cas, il résulte d'une voyelle double (âge pour aage, rôle pour roole) ou d'une simple évolution de la prononciation...

It would make the a in to a double (length) vowel, as vaalid. That is, the speaker would stress the (already stressed) syllable by lengthening the time that it was pronounced.

-=-=- Edit: Example -=-=-

(It may be difficult to think of a double-length vowel in English. Think of a trendy person saying, "[Daahling, can you tell me the way to M&S](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2002/sep/12/shopping.fashion)?" Linguistically, what is happening is a doubling of the vowel length (and the deletion of a post-vocalic r)).

-=-=- Edit ends -=-=-

There is only one vowel with a circumflex in the "Breton" section: the letter *e*. It says that it replaces the dipthong *ae*, as in [encyclopaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences).

Comment: You may find [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/522) interesting as well.